# Can't access variable from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I'm trying to write variables from my code behind but am being told "The name 'X' does not exist in the current context."

When I search for this error, I see that they should be declared public or protected at the class level, and I have done that.

I try writing the variable in default.aspx using:

```
<%=metaRedirect%>
```

or

```
<%#metaRedirect%>
```

My default.aspx.cs is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace go
{

    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected string message1 = "";
        protected string url = "";
        protected string shortCode = "";
        protected string jsRedirect = "";
        protected string metaRedirect = "";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
             //do stuff

    }

}
```

Edit: I have also tried declaring them like this:

```
public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected string message1 { get; set; }
        protected string url { get; set; }
        protected string shortCode { get; set; }
        protected string jsRedirect { get; set; }
        protected string metaRedirect { get; set; }
```

With no difference.

Edit 2: Is it possible I am missing something from the first line of the .aspx file? I have:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" %>
```

Comment: make it public property

Comment: Try making it a property (adding `{get; set;}`) instead of a field.

Comment: I've tried that as well. I'll do it again and see if it makes a difference and update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like your page isn't properly hooked up to the class. Make sure you've got `Inherits="go._default"` in your page header in your aspx page.

**EDIT** After your edit, this is definitely your problem.

Also, you can definitely use fields if you want instead of properties (but I always recommend properties), and you can use protected instead of public. Things shouldn't be public unless you really do want to access them from outside of this class or inheritance chain.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using binding expression you need to call `Page.DataBind()`
in the page_load and make the variable `Public`

```
public string metaRedirect { get; set; }
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
metaRedirect="Hello World.";
Page.DataBind();
}
```

And try:

```
<%#metaRedirect%>
```

or you can just Simply call it like

```
<%= metaRedirect%>
```